# Dynamic View creation, when rendering it to a Canvas fails 

Tags: android

Hi I am trying to draw a complex view, defined by an xml layout to a Bitmap (which is afterwards drawn to a canvas). That view is then updated regularly, when something changed in the data model. 
Changing statically defined TextView works perfect, but adding new Views to a linearLayout is somehow not working. Where is my mistake?

This is how I am adding new Views:

```
           linearLayoutContainer.removeAllViewsInLayout();

            for (int i = 0 ; i < 5; i ++) {

                TextView child = new TextView(getContext());
                child.setText("example" + i);
                child.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                linearLayoutContainer.addView(child, i , new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
                i++;
            }
```

this is how I am crating the bitmap:

```
    sideBarView.refresh();
    sideBarView.invalidate();
    sideBarBitmap = sideBarView.getDrawingCache();
```

which works perfectly for updating the already in xml defined TextViews, but the new added views are not visible.

My xml layout looks like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="some"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutContainer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.33"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

<!-- THE CONTAINER -->

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="0.66"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:text="20%"
    android:textSize="30dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="3dp"
    android:text="35%"
    android:textSize="30dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem. After refreshing my view by adding new views I should have called measure  on the root view again. This is what I did wrong (in pseudo code):

```
init code:
created rootView
measure 
getDrawingCache
draw

update code:
update rootView
invalidate rootView
getDrawingCache
draw
```

So the problem was in the update code, which did not called measure again, so that the child views have not been remeasured , which of course  does not happen when adding a view inside an activity, so thats what is needed:

```
update code:
update rootView
measure
invalidate rootView
getDrawingCache
draw
```

and in real code:

```
private void refreshViews() {

    sideBarView.refresh();

    sideBarView.measure(
            MeasureSpec.getSize(sideBarView.getMeasuredWidth()),
            MeasureSpec.getSize(sideBarView.getMeasuredHeight()));
    sideBarView.layout(0, 0,
            MeasureSpec.getSize(sideBarView.getMeasuredWidth()),
            MeasureSpec.getSize(sideBarView.getMeasuredHeight()));

    sideBarView.invalidate();
    sideBarView.buildDrawingCache();
    sideBarBitmap = sideBarView.getDrawingCache();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling sideBarView.buildDrawingCache() before sideBarView.getDrawingCache(). Your view probably hasn't redrawn itself between the invalidate and the getDrawingCache call, and so wouldn't have rebuilt its cache.

Comment: No that does not work, btw getDrawingCache calls buildDrawingCache after the view was invalidated... this problem drives me crazy :(